# Naming of a file within a for-loop that depends on "i"

Tags: r

Is it possible to save documents within a for-loop such that the i'th run will save a document called i.txt? I tried the obvious:

```
for (i in 1:10) {
...
write.table(temp,file="i.txt",sep="\t", col.names=NA)
}
```

but this just saves one file called i.txt. Any way to do this easily? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you write `file="i.txt"` you are creating a fixed character string, i.e. `"i.txt"`.

You need to add some code that takes the current value of `i` and uses it in the string. One option is to use `paste`:

```
paste(i, ".txt", sep="")
```

Or use the new (in R 2.15.0) shortcut function `paste0` which uses `sep=""` by default

Therefore, try:

```
for (i in 1:10) {
...
write.table(temp,file=paste0(i, ".txt"),sep="\t", col.names=NA)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want a bit more formatting options then have a look at sprintf()

```
i <- c(1, 2, 10, 99, 100)
paste("file", i, ".txt", sep = "")
[1] "file1.txt"   "file2.txt"   "file10.txt"  "file99.txt"  "file100.txt"
sprintf("file%i.txt", i)
[1] "file1.txt"   "file2.txt"   "file10.txt"  "file99.txt"  "file100.txt"
sprintf("file%02i.txt", i)
[1] "file01.txt"  "file02.txt"  "file10.txt"  "file99.txt"  "file100.txt"
sprintf("file%03i.txt", i)
[1] "file001.txt" "file002.txt" "file010.txt" "file099.txt" "file100.txt"
```